# In Vim, how to create a new line in between two lines with one empty line before and another after?

Tags: vim

For example, I have the following lines:

```
one line
another line
one more line
other line
```

However, I would like to add a new line in between, but one line empty before and another after.

```
one line
another line

MY NEWLY inserted line;

one more line
other line
```

As you can see, there is a empty line before `MY NEWLY inserted line;` and another after.

How can I achieve in a easy way?

Normally, I use `o`, `ESC`, `o`, `ESC`, `O`. But I think, this is not the best way. Please help if you know. Thank you.

Comment: Does this need to be done from within `vim` or can you do it with a tool like `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: I am looking for only `vim` solution.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/ This question belongs there, not here.

Comment: @Rob The question is just fine here. There is always going to be overlap between the different StackExchange sites. It's up to the user to decide where they think they get the best answers from.  See also, for example, the overlap between U&L and AskUbuntu, and between U&L and StackOverflow, and between U&L and the Bioinformatics site, etc.

Comment: So what is the purpose of vi stack exchange if not to handle all vi/vim questions? This is an ongoing issue I have with stackexchange. @Kusalananda

Comment: @Rob You may want to bring this to [our meta site](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/). You can't be suggesting that we should ban question that would also be suitable on another SE site? That would, for example, make it impossible to ask about Ubuntu and macOS here. See also [How to identify which questions belong to which site?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2927)

Answer (score 2):

- Place cursor on "another line"
- Press <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- type `MY NEWLY inserted line`
- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>

Or

- Place cursor on "another line"
- Press <kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd>,<kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Press <kbd>O</kbd>, type `MY NEWLY inserted line`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repeating the `o` + `Esc`, there is the [unimpaired plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) (that I
referred to on a [similar question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/31062/edit) I answered) that gives mappings in
normal mode for putting in blank lines without needing to enter insert mode
(among other `[` and `]` based mappings):

> There are linewise mappings. `[<Space>` and `]<Space>` add newlines before
> and after the cursor line. `[e` and `]e` exchange the current line with
> the one above or below it.

Also:

> The . command works with all operator mappings, and will work with the > linewise mappings as well if you install [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat).

So you can add a number of blank lines (I'll use 3 as an example), avoiding
insert mode, by doing:

```
3[<Space>
```

Then drop into insert mode and type!

At first I thought this mapping seemed a bit awkward and counter-intuitive, but
now I use it many times a day and would miss it. With the other `[` and `]`
based mappings from the plugin, it all becomes natural.

For instance, you can exchange the current line with [count] lines above it
with `[e` (or exchange above with `]e`). So to swap a couple of lines you could
do `ddjp` to 'delete, move down a line, and past below' or simply do `]e`.

Answer (score 0):

Just move to the line you want to add something after (`another line` in your example), and then,

1. open a new line by pressing <kbd>o</kbd>,
2. press <kbd>Enter</kbd> an extra time before typing your new line to insert an empty line,
3. press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to terminate the line and to create an empty line after the line you just entered.

Done (press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to get back to normal mode).

This corresponds to the `sed` script

```
/^another line$/ a\
\
MY NEWLY inserted line;\
\
```

or to the `ed` session

```
1;/^another line$/ a

MY NEWLY inserted line;

.
```